# Audit.NET - Is there an option to only output changed values? Default lists all old and all new values

Tags: audit.net

Is there an option to only output changed values? Default lists all old and all new values even though they have not changed. For a large object this gets quite verbose

Comment: You need to provide more information. Which Audit.* libraries are you referencing? What have you tried so far? Please check https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/53 and https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/167